# Zoom in Animation

Tags: android, animation, zooming

I am using `RotateAnimation` for image.
But I also want zoom on image with animation.
Means when my image is rotate then image is also zooming...

How can I do zoom with rotate animation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have one idea, hope it's help.

```
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 180);
ScaleAnimation zoom = new ScaleAnimation(0, 0, 1, 1);

animSet.addAnimation(rotate);
animSet.addAnimation(zoom);

animSet.start();
```

You should change parameters as need your application.

Comment: You should play with properties (It's not very easy to set right parametrs for animation). And added `animSet` animation to your `ImageView` ( or other `View` what you use ).

Comment: The ScaleAnimation constructor is actually ScaleAnimation(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY) so in order to even do anything it will need to be ScaleAnimation(0,1,0,1);

Answer (score 12):

In anim xml, you can work with scale like this:

```
<scale
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromXScale=".1"
    android:fromYScale=".1"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

Comment: AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
  RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,360,img.getWidth()/2,img.getHeight()/2);
  ScaleAnimation zoom = new ScaleAnimation(0, 50, 0, 50);
  animSet.addAnimation(rotate);
  animSet.addAnimation(zoom);
  animSet.setRepeatCount(0);
  animSet.setDuration(500);
  animSet.setFillAfter(true);
        animSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        img.clearAnimation();

Answer (score 12):

### In the Zooming animation is called Scale Animation.

```
 ScaleAnimation scal=new ScaleAnimation(0, 1f, 0, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
    scal.setDuration(500);
    scal.setFillAfter(true);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo)).setAnimation(scal);
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks! :)