# how to zoom in and zoom out animation to the image in android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app with zoom animation in android. like in button onclick event go to the next activity, on that activity i have an image that image should be zoom in with animation. if anybody come across this help me.

Comment: Please refer this link http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html it will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code in your next Activity `onCreate()` method

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        
Animation animZoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);
        
imageView.startAnimation(animZoomin);
```

Create an xml file which defines type of animation to perform. This file should be located under anim folder under **res directory (res ⇒ anim ⇒ zoom_in.xml)**. If you don’t have anim folder in your res directory create one.

put following code in `zoom_in.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
 
    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3"/>
</set>
```

Comment: thank you so much.. its working, i want to reduce the zoom in size of the image. where can i change?

Comment: you have change in android:toXScale="3", android:toYScale="3" to android:toXScale="2", android:toYScale="2" in zoom_in.xml file.

Comment: Thank you, will you please give me the scale properties for flip animation(bottom to top) with curl for an activity on button click.

Comment: you have change in android:pivotY="50%" to android:pivotY="200%" or android:pivotY="300%" as you want in in zoom_in.xml file.

Comment: Ok thank you, can i give curl animation to whole activity on button click and after the animation show the content in same activity, is it possible in android?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some topics on StackOverFlow similar :

[zoom in and zoom out animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904432/zoom-in-and-zoom-out-animation-in-android)

[Zoom in Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167199/zoom-in-animation)

And here is a article on developer.android.com :

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Hope that helps. :]