# Apply Scale Animation to a Button

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

I am trying to apply Animation to a button. What I want to do is when I press a button depending on the pressure I put, the button should scale down or up accordingly. If I release, it should come back to its original size. How do I do it?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167199/zoom-in-animation/26624761#26624761

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for scale animation

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
```

For more Information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html